# apache configure site maintainance page

Tags: apache

I am trying to configure in apache httpd.conf for the below scenario. Can anyone please advise how to do it.

When the apache instance is up and some one tries to hit below url

http://mydomain.com/xxx

It should display content exists in sitemaintenance.html without changing url context path.

Assume sitemaintenance.html resides in /usr/local/apache/my-apache-instance/htdocs/sitemaintenance.html

Here xxx is a subdomain which is hosted separately from main domain (mydomain.com).

-KS

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this into `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` for your sub-domain:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond  /usr/local/apache/my-apache-instance/htdocs/sitemaintenance.html -f
 RewriteRule ^.*$ /sitemaintenance.html [PT,L]
```

The condition in `RewriteCond` enables rewrite only if that file exists, so you can dynamically add or delete it, without re-starting Apache or changing `.htaccess`.